# always getting null response while calling WCF Rest service with ajax calls

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf, rest

This is probably a very common problem but I couldn't get through it with the solutions from internet . First let me introduce the issue , 
I have a Rest WCF service exposed as follows :

```
   // Service operation that retrieves the KPI result
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "/KPI/{monthYear}/{currentYear}/{companyCode}/{divisionCode}/{shopCode}/{parameterName}/{kpiCode}")]
    int Get_SY_KPI(string monthYear,string currentYear,string companyCode, string divisionCode, string shopCode, string parameterName, string kpiCode);
```

I'm trying to call this service from an html form with a simple ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:5547/FoxWcfRest.svc/KPI/March/2014/001/001/003/END_QUANTITY_INDICATOR_HP/002",           
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(response) {

                alert(response);

            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert("Oops");
            }
        });
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong but I'm getting null alert msg , I've read something about crossdomain issues .. anybody could help ?

Comment: It's only a typo .. still same problem

Comment: if you add a debug breakpoint at your service method and execute your ajax request does the debug breakpoint fire?

Comment: @NeilThompson no I added a breakpoint , it turned out that the ajax request doesnt fire it ..

Comment: update: after removing the project directory from IIS manager , I'm able to hit the breakpoint but with no success having a result..